# Is it thread safe to call ruby constants with a stabby lambda?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, csv, constants

Is it thread-safe to call ruby/rails `CONSTANTS` with a stabby lambda or proc?

I know constants defined as dynamic methods is discouraged in the ruby community, as constant definitions, on their own, are not thread-safe and can function dangerously like global variables subject to race conditions.

However, if you define a constant to receive a stabby lambda or proc, could that make the code thread-safe?

E.g. this blog post [on defining constants using procs/lambda's](https://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2015/02/27/value-assignment-and-deferment-with-lambdasprocs/) suggests that constants defined as lambda and procs can be trusted to reliably invoke uniquely each time:

```rb
class Foo
  LAMBDA = lambda {Time.now}
  PROC = proc {Time.now}
  STABBYLAMBDA = ->{Time.now}
  BEGINBLOCK = begin Time.now end

  def Foo.the_time
    Time.now
  end
  METHODBLOCK = Foo.the_time
end

Foo::LAMBDA[]
# => 2019-09-16 22:39:51 -0700
Foo::LAMBDA[]
# => 2019-09-16 22:39:53 -0700
Foo::PROC[]
# => 2019-09-16 22:39:55 -0700 
Foo::PROC[]
# => 2019-09-16 22:39:57 -0700 
Foo::STABBYLAMBDA[]
# => 2019-09-16 22:39:59 -0700 
Foo::STABBYLAMBDA[]
# => 2019-09-16 22:40:01 -0700 
Foo::BEGINBLOCK
# => 2019-09-16 22:39:51 -0700
Foo::BEGINBLOCK
# => 2019-09-16 22:39:51 -0700
Foo::METHODBLOCK
# => 2019-09-16 22:39:51 -0700 
Foo::METHODBLOCK
# => 2019-09-16 22:39:51 -0700
```

But does that extend to thread safety too?

---

E.g. in this code I have a Rails Service Object that runs in multi-threaded Sidekiq that extracts data for uploading CSVs:

```rb
class ExportReferralData < ServiceObject


  EXPORT_COLUMNS = ["Referrer_phone_number", "Referrer_ID", "Referee_phone_number", "Referee_ID", "Date_Approved"].freeze

  EXPORT_ROW = ->(referral){
    [referral.customer.identifier, referral.customer.accountable.internal_identifier, referral.friend.identifier, referral.friend.accountable.internal_identifier, referral.approved_at.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")]
  }


  def initialize
  end

  def call
    data = data_for_csv( Referral.all )

    UploadFile.put(file_path) do |file|
      create_csv(file, data)
    end
  end

  private

  def data_for_csv(active_record_query_result)
    active_record_query_result.inject([]) do |result, item|
      result << EXPORT_ROW.call(item)
    end
  end


  def create_csv(file, export_data)
    CSV(file, headers:true, force_quotes: true) do |csv|
      csv << EXPORT_COLUMNS
      export_data.each do |export_row|
        csv << export_row
      end
    end
    file.rewind
  end

  def file_path
    "upload/APPROVED_#{Time.current.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")}.csv"
  end
end
```

This multi-threaded code defines `EXPORT_ROW` to be a constant that equals a stabby lambda (not a proc), which then takes any `referral` ActiveRecord object it gets passed to build each CSV row dynamically.  This local variable inside the lambda then calls ActiveRecord queries.

Stylistically I like how this code looks, but I want to be sure that my use of `EXPORT_ROW.call(item)` here is actually thread-safe, especially when invoking methods like ActiveRecord queries.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: No idea, but why wouldn't you just use a Mutex to be sure?

Comment: What would using a Mutex here look like?

Comment: "constants defined as lambda's (but not procs) can be trusted to reliably invoke uniquely each time" — I have no idea what that would mean, nor can find any mention of it in the article.  The fact that you got two same results with proc just means you executed them too fast, so the time didn't have... err, time... to change. The article also is not at all about thread safety. All `Proc` objects (regardless of whether obtained through `lambda`, `proc` or `->`) are immutable, so they have zero impact on thread safety (though their contents certainly can be thread-safe or not).

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for pointing that out, I ran the code locally again and updated my example.  I've confirmed only `Foo::BEGINBLOCK` and `Foo::METHODBLOCK` fail to reinvoke `Time.now`.

Comment: Neither of them are `Proc`; they are the result of the excecution of the expression you gave them (a `Date`, in this case).

Comment: If a proc or lambda is passed an AR object with queries like my example, will each thread evaluate the AR objects passed into them from a CONSTANT uniquely without sharing state?  I.e. is the `referral` variable inside the proc/lambda closed off to other threads?

Comment: @KelseyHannan I understand why it's a bit confusing .... Highly recommend reading up on mutability in Ruby, and how to use a mutex to remove race conditions in multithreaded code. There is no visible multithreading going on but I can't rule out that it could happen (if you're using a multithreaded webserver, and this service is called from a controller action, for example). For this question's sake I would recommend boiling it down to a hypothetical scenario you think you _would_ have the race condition, maybe a shorter snippet of code

Comment: _I know constants defined as dynamic methods is discouraged in the ruby community_ - sorry, can you mention a source of this statement?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding whether or not the lambda is thread safe, the answer is the same as it would be for a method; it depends on what you do inside the lambda. As long as you are not making modifications in multiple threads to shared state (e.g. the same object), you're ok.

When an instance of your `Foo` class is created, the `LAMBDA` constant is created, and initialized with the lambda object on the right side of `=`. Subsequently, every reference of `LAMBDA` returns that lambda instance.

It is safe to reference `LAMBDA` from multiple threads because it is simply returning on object. However, although *referencing* `LAMBDA` may be safe, that doesn't necessarily mean that *executing* it is safe. That depends on the content of the lambda. If the lambda contains code that modifies any shared state, that might be a problem. It looks like your referral object used inside the lambda is merely reading data. That should be fine.

It doesn't matter whether it's a lambda, a method, or a block passed to `Thread.new`; it just matters what code is being executed inside that thread.

One thing I don't understand is, if the `call` method is getting *all* the referrals, how does Sidekiq know how to divide that into multiple jobs/threads? It seems to me that this job would run in its entirety in a single thread; in which case the question is moot, no? But then I'm not familiar with Sidekiq so I may be wrong.

Some other points:

- Please, please do not use the `[]` notation to call a lambda. Yes, it is legal, but it is unnecessarily confusing and misleading. Much better to use `.call` or `.()` (my favorite).
- when you say " a constant that equals a stabby lambda", you imply that a stabby lambda object is different from a non-stabby lambda object. Either way it is a lambda object; the stabby is just an *abbreviated notation used to create it*.
- Similarly, "constants defined as lambda and procs can be trusted to reliably invoke uniquely each time" reveals a misunderstanding of what a lambda or proc is...that's like saying that a *method* "can be trusted to reliably invoke uniquely each time"; *of course* it can. A constant is like a variable in that it is a reference to an object. It doesn't add any functionality to the thing it refers to.

If you'd like to research lambdas further, I've given some talks and written some articles about them. Here are some resources:

- Ruby Lambdas Presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvQ_K2Edu-Y
- Slides for above: https://speakerdeck.com/keithrbennett/functional-programming-in-ruby-with-lambdas-1e80e559-90bd-4e73-acef-86e84ff209f3
- Blog (multiple articles about lambdas): https://blog.bbs-software.com/blog